# Align Text/Content center inside DIV tag

Tags: html, css, styles

I am designing a page with tile contents. I was able to position the tiles center but couldn't do that with its content. The tiles content's vertical alignment is centered but the horizontal alignment is aligned towards left. Any tweaks that I am missing??

Here is my script,

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
        <div class="tile-container">
            <div class="tile">
                <p>Tile 1</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tile">
                <p>Tile 2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tile">
                <p>Tile 3</p>
            </div>
            <div class="tile">
                <p>Tile 4</p>
            </div>               

        </div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.content {
    margin-top: 10%;
}

.tile-container {
    width: 640px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    text-align: center;
}

.tile {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    height: 250px;
    width: 250px;
    background: red;
    margin: 8px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: 0;
}

    .tile:hover {
        background: red;
        z-index: 100;
        -moz-transform: scale(1.1,1);
        -ms-transform: scale(1.1,1);
        -o-transform: scale(1.1,1);
        -webkit-transform: scale(1.1,1);
        transform: scale(1.1,1);
        box-shadow: 0 5px 10px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }

.tile-container p {
    margin: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't use `position: absolute` for the `p` elements. http://jsfiddle.net/30u4579e/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the shown solutions are absolutely static. If you had to handle different content you should go a different way. Use `table` and `table-cell`. This will make your markup responsive to the content.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/stefan_wave/30u4579e/3/)

UPDATE:

I wrapped the `p`in a additional `div`and changed the css:

```
.tile div{
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.tile div p{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.tile-container p {
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That did worked. So one more question, what if I need to add a badge notification to these tiles? will it have a any side effect?

Answer (score 1):

Absolute positions are no fun:

```
.tile-container p {
    margin-top:50%;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

please try this

```
  .tile-container p{

   position:relative;

}
```

Comment: Please add additional information to your question.